# Count all characters between 2 words in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, foundation

Is it possible to count the number of characters between 2 words in a NSString? Here's the string

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test string."];
```

I want to count the characters between the word "This" and the word "string".

Is this possible

Comment: No, sorry, it's impossible... (of course it is possible. Did you try searching **at all?**)

Comment: Yes of course i did. I'm just 14yo and just started with Obj-C. Sorry i am asking you a question... -,-"

Comment: believe or not, I started learning iOS development at the age of 15. I didn't have to ask such questions "for some reason"...

Comment: Everyone, thanks for helping me! It all works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first find the range and get the substring from it

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test string."];
NSRange range1 = [myString rangeOfString:@"This"];
NSRange range2 = [myString rangeOfString:@"string"];
NSRange rangeSubString = NSMakeRange(range1.location + range1.length, range2.location - range1.location - range1.length);
NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange:rangeSubString];
```

then you can count the character of this string

```
NSUInteger characterCount = [subString length];
```

Answer (score 2):

You might do something like this :

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test string."];

NSInteger charCountBetween = -1;
NSRange thisRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"This"];
NSRange stringRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"string"];
if( thisRange.location != NSNotFound && stringRange.location != NSNotFound )
{
    charCountBetween = fabs(thisRange.location - stringRange.location);
    if( thisRange.location > stringRange.location )
    {
        charCountBetween -= stringRange.length;
    }
    else
    {
        charCountBetween -= thisRange.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myString = @"This is a test !";
NSRange match = [myString rangeOfString: @"This"];
NSRange match1 = [myString rangeOfString: @"test"];

int nbChar = match1.location - match.location;
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a test string";
NSRange firstRange = [string rangeOfString:@"This"];
NSRange secondRange = [string rangeOfString:@"string"];
if (firstRange.location != NSNotFound &&
    secondRange.location != NSNotFound &&
    secondRange.location > firstRange.location) {
    NSLog(@"Characters between: %d", secondRange.location - (firstRange.location + firstRange.length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `NSRange`:

```
NSRange range1 = [myString rangeOfString:@"This"];
NSRange range2 = [myString rangeOfString:@"string"];
NSUInteger numberOfChars = range2.location - range1.location;
```